# Python struct.unpack(ing) when there are multiple byte-orders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, binaryfiles, iterable-unpacking

I have a function that reads a binary file and then unpacks the file's contents using struct.unpack(). My function works just fine. It is faster if/when I unpack the whole of the file using a long 'format' string. Problem is that sometimes the byte-alignment changes so my format string (which is invalid) would look like '<10sHHb>llh' (this is just an example (they are usually way longer)). Is there any ultra slick/pythonic way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing super-slick, but if speed counts, the `struct` module top-level functions are wrappers that have to repeatedly recheck a cache for the actual `struct.Struct` instance corresponding to the format string; while you must make separate format strings, you might solve part of your speed problem by avoiding that repeated cache check.

Instead of doing:

```
buffer = memoryview(somedata)
allresults = []
while buffer:
    allresults += struct.unpack_from('<10sHHb', buffer)
    buffer = buffer[struct.calcsize('<10sHHb'):]
    allresults += struct.unpack_from('>llh', buffer)
    buffer = buffer[struct.calcsize('>llh'):]
```

You'd do:

```
buffer = memoryview(somedata)
structa = struct.Struct('<10sHHb')
structb = struct.Struct('>llh')
allresults = []
while buffer:
    allresults += structa.unpack_from(buffer)
    buffer = buffer[structa.size:]
    allresults += structb.unpack_from(buffer)
    buffer = buffer[structb.size:]
```

No, it's not much nicer looking, and the speed gains aren't likely to blow you away. But you've got *weird* data, so this is the least brittle solution.

If you want unnecessarily clever/brittle solutions, you could do this with `ctypes` custom `Structure`s, nesting `BigEndianStructure`(s) inside a `LittleEndianStructure` or vice-versa. For your example format :

```
from ctypes import *

class BEStruct(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [('x', 2 * c_long), ('y', c_short)]
    _pack_ = True

class MainStruct(LittleEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [('a', 10 * c_char), ('b', 2 * c_ushort), ('c', c_byte), ('big', BEStruct)]
    _pack_ = True
```

would give you a structure such that you could do:

```
mystruct = MainStruct()
memoryview(mystruct).cast('B')[:] = bytes(range(25))
```

and you'd then get results in the expected order, e.g.:

```
>>> hex(mystruct.b[0])  # Little endian as expected in main struct
'0xb0a'
>>> hex(mystruct.big.x[0]) # Big endian from inner big endian structure
'0xf101112'
```

While clever in a way, it's likely it will run slower (`ctypes` attribute lookup is weirdly slow in my experience), and unlike `struct` module functions, you can't just unpack into top-level named variables in a single line, it's attribute access all the way.